# How to extract date from Date Picker and display selected date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to extract date from Date Picker and display selected date?

Comment: I think when someone down-votes a question. He/She should explain the reason so the person everyone will know and improve his/her questions in the future. I suppose this question got -1 because Veer didn't even (or seem to have) tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set IBOutLet for your DatePicker (as datePicker).
Now code as:

```
NSDate *date =  self.datePicker.date;
```

Comment: Thanx, I am new to iphone programming, so have only basic questions,,,

Answer (score 0):

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/10/how-to-use-uidatepicker-from-uikit-in-iphone-programming/

Good read for your question

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var selectedDate: UIDatePicker!

var date = self.selectedDate.date

println(date)
```